# How to fix NotImplementedError?

Tags: python, textblob, text-processing

I'm trying to use `TextBlobDE.correct()` method. In each run of the script below i get the error below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textblob_de/blob.py", line 523, in correct
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

My script :

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob_de import TextBlobDE as TextBlob

Text_Attribute = %{textAttribute}

def spellingCorrection(text) :   
  b = TextBlob(text)
  return b.correct()

def rm_main(data):
  data['corrected_text'] = data[Text_Attribute].apply(spellingCorrection)
  return data
```

Can someone lead me to the error and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look on `correct` function [source code](https://textblob-de.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/textblob_de/blob.html#BaseBlob.correct) will reveal the answer:

```py
def correct(self):
        """Correct the spelling of the word. Returns the word with the highest
        confidence using the spelling corrector.

        .. versionadded:: 0.6.0 (``textblob``)

        """
        # return Word(self.spellcheck()[0][0])
        raise NotImplementedError
```

As you can see, the code of the function raise immediately this error. In simple words: textblob-de doesn't support `correct` method yet.

TextblobDe is an extension of textblob for German language, so obviously it should implement `correct` method relevant to German language. Unfortunately, developers didn't do so yet. Maybe in the future...